# Deploy Sqlite database to apk

Tags: android, c++, qt, sqlite

I got a couple of questions :
 Where can I locate installed android apk on my mobile
 I can not open the database 
 Where should i copy Database file on my hard

here is pro file :

```
ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android

 deployment.files += Poem.db
 deployment.path = /android/assets
 INSTALLS += deployment
```

connection file:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("Poem.db");
QFile dfile("assets:/Poem.db");
if (dfile.exists())
{
    dfile.copy("./Poem.db");
    QFile::setPermissions("./Poem.db",QFile::WriteOwner |     QFile::ReadOwner);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the installation is successful app logo will appear along with other apps. 
You can copy by code to application folder or other folder you want .

```
    QString path1 = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation);
    QString path = path1 +"/Appfolder/sample.db";
    if(QFile::copy("assets:/sample.db", path))
    {
        qDebug() <<"db copied" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved my problem with [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/94088/deploy-sqlite-database-with-apk/5) thread.